# media query not being responsive

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to change the CSS when the screen width is less than `320px`.

Currently it is stuck at the `min-width` media query and doesn't go to the `max-width` media query when I shrink my screen.

I added this html to my index page:
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Here is a portion of my CSS:

```
div#imageColumn {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    margin:10px;
}
div#contentColumn {
    float:left;
    color:white;
    background-color: black;
    margin:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px){
    div#contentColumn {
    width:75%;
    }

    div#imageColumn {
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px){
    div#imageColumn {
        float:right;
        width:45%;
    }

    div#contentColumn {
        width:25%;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT: It is half-way working now.  The @Media seems to be firing for some attributes but not for others.  The text is moving to the bottom of the screen at 810, but the font size of the h1 object is not changing.

CSS:
`

```
body {
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    }

div#WmStephenScott {
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: #C94B5B;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    padding-left:40px;
    }
div#contactForm {
    float:right;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
h1#WmStephenScott {
    padding-left:40px;
    font-size:40px;
    }
h3#contactMe {
    float:right;
    color:black;
    padding-right:80px;
    padding-top:200px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
p {
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;
    }

aside {
    float:left;
    background-color:'F0E4C9';
    color: white;
    padding-left:40px;
    opacity:1;
    width:20%;
    }
div#imageColumn {
        color:white;
        background-color:black;
        margin:10px;
    }
div#contentColumn {
        float:left;
        color:white;
        background-color: black;
        margin:10px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width:810x){
    div#contentColumn {
        width:50%;
    }

    div#imageColumn {
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:50%;
    }

    aside {
        font-size:20px;
        padding:5px;
    }

    h1#WmStephenScott {
        font-size:20px;
        padding-left:15px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:811px){
    div#imageColumn {
        float:right;
        width:45%;
    }

    div#contentColumn {
        width:25%;
    }
}




div#feedbackFormDiv {
    background-color:#C94B5B;
    float:right;
    padding-right:40px;
}

head {
    }
}`
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
          <title>Steve Scott</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/stylesheet.css')}}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-2.1.0.js')}}"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/script.js')}}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='WmStephenScott'>
            <h3 id='contactMe'>Contact</h3>
            <h1 id='WmStephenScott'>Wm. Stephen Scott</h1>

        </div>

        <aside>
            <div id='aside'>
                <br/>
                <h2 id='AboutMe'>About Myself</h2>
                <br/>
                <h2 id='Code'>Code</h2>
                <br/>
                <h2 id='Geo'>Geo</h2>
                <br/>
                <h2 id='Design'>Design</h2>
                <br/>
            </div>  
        </aside>
        <div id='contentColumn'>

        </div>
        <div id='imageColumn'>
        </div>
<!--
<div id='feedbackFormDiv'>
<h2></h2>
</div>
-->

    </footer>
    </body>
    <footer>

</html>
```

Comment: post your html codes

Comment: Sorry, but is a stupid. Ur code is nothing understanding. Show html, show pics after and before resize in ur desing.

Comment: I am having a problem now.  Some of the CSS is changing, but some of it is not.  Here is the CSS

Comment: I figured out my problem.  The h1 listed before the overrode my @media specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media queries are in conflict, because your `max-width:320px` and `min-width:320px` are at the same value,

So you have to use put `min-width:321px` before `max-width:320px`, otherwise it will override it, remember CSS stands for cascading. and notice that I used `321px` in `min-width` to not make conflict between queries.

```css
div#imageColumn {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    margin:10px;
}

div#contentColumn {
    float:left;
    color:white;
    background-color: black;
    margin:10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:321px) {
  div#imageColumn {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
  }
  div#contentColumn {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  div#contentColumn {
    width: 75%;
  }
  div#imageColumn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I can see the potential for conflict at `320px` but if the specificity is equal then that later would win out right? This [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/myrygh6e/) has the OP's original code with `min-height` added so we can see the elements and it appears to be working. Am I missing something? By the way, I agree with doing the `1px` bump though, makes the intent more clear.

Comment: exactly the later would win, in OP's case the later is `min-width` which is at `320px` like `max-width`, so it **only** applies the `min-width`, never the `max-width` therefore OP can't see when screen is less the 320px